# Dataframe index Error orient in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx

while trying to reproduce this example : https://github.com/ipython-books/cookbook-2nd-code/blob/master/chapter14_graphgeo/02_airports.ipynb I get the following error on this code :

```
pos = {airport: (v['lon'], v['lat'])
       for airport, v in airports_us.to_dict('index').items()}
```

the output is :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-59fee485c0ec> in <module>
      1 
      2 pos = {airport: (v['lon'], v['lat'])
----> 3        for airport, v in airports_us.to_dict('index').items()}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_dict(self, orient, into)
   1314             if not self.index.is_unique:
   1315                 raise ValueError(
-> 1316                     "DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'."
   1317                 )
   1318             return into_c((t[0], dict(zip(self.columns, t[1:])))

ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.
```

Comment: Did you change the `airport` dataframe? I tried to run this notebook and it works for me. Also try to re-run all cells.

Comment: okay I'll rerun it again and answer you

Comment: @vurmux still getting the same error, is it possible to be from the notebook?

Comment: Did you change the `airport` dataframe manually in code? What version of Python do you use? The problem definetly not in notebook.

Comment: @vurmux no i didn't , i copied and pasted....I have 3.7 and the 3.5 installed in the laptop

Comment: Try to download the whole .ipynb file and run it cell-by-cell. Maybe you just forgot to copy something?

Comment: @vurmux i rechecked many times , i'll try to rdownload python again and if doesn't work ill try on another laptop n see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they changed the underlying [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipython-books/cookbook-2nd-data/master/airports.dat).
The problem is not all the airports in `airports_us` have an IATA code assigned.
This you see with

```py
print(len(airports_us))
# 1435
print(len(set(airports_us.index)))
# 1334
# use to display all keys
# print(set(airports_us.index))
```

You can get select the unique items with the following code

```
unique_index = set(airports_us.index)
unique_index.remove(np.nan)
airports_us_index = airports_us.index.isin(unique_index)
airports_us = airports_us[airports_us_index]
```

(which is maybe not the best way to do this with pandas, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the function df.dropna() in pandas on the iata codes columms should clean your data